# Caesar's cypher encryption algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, encryption, modulus, algebra

> Caesar's cypher is the simplest encryption algorithm. It adds a fixed value to the ASCII (unicode) value of each character of a text. In other words, it shifts the characters. Decrypting a text is simply shifting it back by the same amount, that is, it substract the same value from the characters.

My task is to write a function that:

- accepts two arguments: the first is the character vector to be encrypted, and the second is the shift amount.
- returns one output, which is the encrypted text.
- needs to work with all the visible ASCII characters from space to `~` (ASCII codes of 32 through 126). If the shifted code goes outside of this range, it should wrap around. For example, if we shift `~` by `1`, the result should be space. If we shift space by `-1`, the result should be `~`.

This is my MATLAB code:

```
function [coded] = caesar(input_text, shift)
x = double(input_text); %converts char symbols to double format
for ii = 1:length(x) %go through each element
    if (x(ii) + shift > 126) & (mod(x(ii) + shift, 127) < 32)
        x(ii) = mod(x(ii) + shift, 127) + 32; %if the symbol + shift > 126, I make it 32
    elseif (x(ii) + shift > 126) & (mod(x(ii) + shift, 127) >= 32)
        x(ii) = mod(x(ii) + shift, 127);
    elseif (x(ii) + shift < 32) & (126 + (x(ii) + shift - 32 + 1) >= 32)
        x(ii) = 126 + (x(ii) + shift - 32 + 1);
    elseif (x(ii) + shift < 32) & (126 + (x(ii) + shift - 32 + 1) < 32)
        x(ii) = abs(x(ii) - 32 + shift - 32);
    else x(ii) = x(ii) + shift;
    end
end
     coded = char(x); % converts double format back to char
end
```

I can't seem to make the wrapping conversions correctly (e.g. from 31 to 126, 30 to 125, 127 to 32, and so on). How should I change my code to do that?

Comment: You can't just say "it doesn't work properly" without showing us what inputs you provided, what output you expected and what output you got. Regardless, this code is needlessly complex, which makes it difficult to debug. I don't know how strict the requirements of this assignment are (e.g. you **must** use a loop), but if you have some freedom, consider that you could use the **strengths of MATLAB** - and apply `mod`, `-` and `+` to your entire input _at one go_. BTW, since your inputs are always integers, you might want to use some integer data type like `int64` (instead of `double`).

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Try your code by hand with pen and paper for a small failing example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you even start coding something like this, you should have a firm grasp of how to approach the problem.

The main obstacle you encountered is how to apply the modulus operation to your data, seeing how `mod` "wraps" inputs to the range of `[0 modPeriod-1]`, while your own data is in the range `[32 126]`. To make `mod` useful in this case we perform an intermediate step of **shifting** of the input to the range that `mod` "likes", i.e. from some `[minVal maxVal]` to `[0 modPeriod-1]`.

So we need to find two things: the size of the required shift, and the size of the period of the `mod`. The first one is easy, since this is just `-minVal`, which is the negative of the ASCII value of the first character, which is space (written as `' '` in MATLAB). As for the period of the `mod`, this is just the size of your "alphabet", which happens to be "1 larger than the maximum value, after shifting", or in other words - `maxVal-minVal+1`. Essentially, what we're doing is the following

```
input -> shift to 0-based ("mod") domain -> apply mod() -> shift back -> output
```

Now take a look how this can be written using MATLAB's vectorized notation:

```matlab
function [coded] = caesar(input_text, shift)
FIRST_PRINTABLE = ' ';
LAST_PRINTABLE = '~';
N_PRINTABLE_CHARS = LAST_PRINTABLE - FIRST_PRINTABLE  + 1;

coded = char(mod(input_text - FIRST_PRINTABLE + shift, N_PRINTABLE_CHARS) + FIRST_PRINTABLE);
```

Here are some tests:

```
>> caesar('blabla', 1)
ans =
    'cmbcmb'
>> caesar('cmbcmb', -1)
ans =
    'blabla'
>> caesar('blabla', 1000)
ans =
    '5?45?4'
>> caesar('5?45?4', -1000)
ans =
    'blabla'
```

Comment: The important stuff your code is doing has nothing to do with vectorization and everything to do with shifting the active region down for the `mod`. You might want to explain that, rather than encouraging the OP to "try to understand how this example works" (they were already trying to understand things, that's why they're here).

Comment: @Sneftel This is clearly a homework assignment (see q before my edit if this is not evident). I was trying to teach the asker something without spoon-feeding them, since the alternative was to let this question get closed with no answer at all. I understand you might disagree with my "teaching method" of purposeful vagueness, but I do believe this could be helpful as it is.|| Also, you are right that a big part of the solution is the shifting, but please don't underestimate the value of vectorization when it comes to concise code (this is especially important for [tag:matlab] code).

Comment: Try rewriting the code to vectorize the conditionals rather than removing them, and you'll see the relative value of vectorization here. I agree with not spoon-feeding homework answers, but surely the way to teach the OP to fish is to explain the issues, rather than to just give them the answer as a block of code?

Comment: @Sneftel Thank you for your comments, I have added an explanation about using the modulus operation correctly in this scenario.

Comment: All that is exactly what the OP needs to know. +1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer @Dev-iL now I get how we can use _mod_ for this problem and thanks for showing me all the advantages of vectorization in MATLAB. Also thanks for editing and formatting my question, I've learned these tips.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve it using the idea of periodic functions :
periodic function repeats itself every cycle and every cycle is equal to *2π* ...

like periodic functions ,we have a function that repeats itself every 95 values

the cycle = 126-32+1 ;
we add one because the '32' is also in the cycle ...

So if the value of the character exceeds *'126'* we subtract 95 ,

> i.e. if the value =127(*bigger than 126*) then it is equivalent to
>   127-95=32 .

&if the value is less than 32 we subtract 95.

> i.e. if the value= 31 (*less than 32*) then it is equivalent to 31+95
>   =126..

Now we will translate that into codes :

```
function out= caesar(string,shift)
value=string+shift;

for i=1:length(value)
    while value(i)<32
        value(i)=value(i)+95;
    end
    while value(i)>126 
        value(i)=value(i)-95;
    end

end
out=char(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

First i converted the output(shift+ text_input) to char.

```
function coded= caesar(text_input,shift)
coded=char(text_input+shift);

for i=1:length(coded)
    while coded(i)<32
        coded(i)=coded(i)+95;
    end
    while coded(i)>126 
        coded(i)=coded(i)-95;
    end

end
```

Comment: Hi @evan_ this basically repeats the code of another answer already given in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is one short code:

```
function coded = caesar(v,n)
C = 32:126;
v = double(v);

for i = 1:length(v)
    x = find(C==v(i));
    C = circshift(C,-n);
    v(i) = C(x);
    C = 32:126;
end
coded = char(v);
end
```